Fastest way to extract relevant rows - pandas
I've got a very large pandas df that has the fields group, id_a, id_b and score, ordered by score so the highest is at the top. There is a row for every possible combination of id_a and id_b. I want to extract rows so that there is only one row per id_a and id_b, which reflects the highest score possible without repeating IDs.
Showing an example of what this might look like - the resulting df has 3 rows, with all ids in id_a and id_b appearing once each. In the case of A2/B2 and A1/B1, the row with the best score for both IDs has been used. In the case of A3, the best score related to a row with B1, which had already been used, so the next best score combined with B3 is used.
Input table

Desired result

To achieve this, I've got a loop iterating through the original df. This is incredibly slow with a large dataset. I've tried coming up with alternatives but I am struggling, for e.g.:

Once a row is identified for a pair of IDs, I could remove those IDs from the original df, but I'm not sure how to do this without restarting the loop
I could split things by group (the example only has 1 group but there would be lots more, with IDs unique across groups) - however this doesn't seem to save time

Can anybody offer any other approaches? Thank you!
import pandas as pd
# Create sample df
group = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
id_a = ['A2', 'A1', 'A3', 'A3', 'A2', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']
id_b = ['B2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B3', 'B2']
score = [0.99, 0.98, 0.97, 0.96, 0.93, 0.5, 0.41, 0.4, 0.2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': group, 'id_a': id_a, 'id_b': id_b, 'score': score})

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

# Extract required rows
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if len(result) == 0:
        result = row.to_frame().T
    else:
        if ((row['id_a'] in result['id_a'].tolist())
                or (row['id_b'] in result['id_b'].tolist())):
            continue
        else:
            result = pd.concat([result, row.to_frame().T[result.columns]])


This looks to me line a linear_sum_assignment problem (i.e. maximizing the sum of score for unique pairs of id_a/id_b), you could use a pivot per group to do this:
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

out = {}
for group, g in (df.pivot(index=['group', 'id_a'],
                          columns='id_b', values='score')
                   .groupby(level=0)):
    idx, col = linear_sum_assignment(g, maximize=True)
    out[group] = pd.DataFrame({'id_a': g.index.get_level_values(1)[idx],
                               'id_b': g.columns[col],
                               'score': g.values[idx, col]})

out = pd.concat(out, names=['group']).reset_index(0)

Alternative code (does the same thing with a different order of the steps). This way is preferred if you don't have the same id_a/id_b across groups (this avoids building a large pivoted intermediate):
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
import numpy as np

out = []
for group, g in df.sort_values(by=['id_a', 'id_b']).groupby('group'):
    tmp = g.pivot(index='id_a', columns='id_b', values='score')
    idx, col = linear_sum_assignment(tmp, maximize=True)
    out.append(g.iloc[np.ravel_multi_index((idx, col), tmp.shape)])
out = pd.concat(out)

Output:
   group id_a id_b  score
0      1   A1   B1   0.98
1      1   A2   B2   0.99
2      1   A3   B3   0.96


Thanks, this looks good! I'm using out.append(pd.concat([g[(g['id_a']==tmp.index[i]) & (g['id_b']==tmp.columns[c])] for i, c in zip(idx, col)])) instead of out.append(g.iloc[np.ravel_multi_index((idx, col), tmp.shape)]) - I'm worried this is slower, but for some reason np.ravel_multi_index((idx, col), tmp.shape) was giving me indices that didn't exist in g, but I can't work out why that is happening.

@Jaccar if you can craft a small example that reproduces this error, I can have a look.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)  


group = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
id_a = ['A2', 'A1', 'A3', 'A3', 'A2', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']
id_b = ['B2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B3', 'B2']
score = [0.99, 0.98, 0.97, 0.96, 0.93, 0.5, 0.41, 0.4, 0.2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': group, 'id_a': id_a, 'id_b': id_b, 'score': score})
print(df)
"""
   group id_a id_b  score
0      1   A2   B2   0.99
1      1   A1   B1   0.98
2      1   A3   B1   0.97
3      1   A3   B3   0.96
4      1   A2   B1   0.93
5      1   A1   B2   0.50
6      1   A1   B3   0.41
7      1   A2   B3   0.40
8      1   A3   B2   0.20

"""
# Efficiently group by ID combination with max score per group
result = (df.groupby(['id_a', 'id_b'])
          .agg(score=('score', 'max'))
          .reset_index())
print('result :')
print(result)
"""
result :
  id_a id_b  score
0   A1   B1   0.98
1   A1   B2   0.50
2   A1   B3   0.41
3   A2   B1   0.93
4   A2   B2   0.99
5   A2   B3   0.40
6   A3   B1   0.97
7   A3   B2   0.20
8   A3   B3   0.96
"""

df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['id_a', 'id_b'])
print('df_sorted :')
print(df_sorted)
"""
df_sorted :
   group id_a id_b  score
1      1   A1   B1   0.98
5      1   A1   B2   0.50
6      1   A1   B3   0.41
4      1   A2   B1   0.93
0      1   A2   B2   0.99
7      1   A2   B3   0.40
2      1   A3   B1   0.97
8      1   A3   B2   0.20
3      1   A3   B3   0.96
"""

# Create cost matrix (negative scores) using pivot_table
cost_matrix = (df_sorted.pivot_table(index='id_a',
                                     columns='id_b',
                                     values='score',
                                     fill_value= -np.inf) * -1)

print(cost_matrix)
"""
id_b    B1    B2    B3
id_a                  
A1   -0.98 -0.50 -0.41
A2   -0.93 -0.99 -0.40
A3   -0.97 -0.20 -0.96
"""

# Handle missing values
# Solve assignment problem (minimize cost)
rows, cols = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix.fillna(np.inf))  
print(rows)#[0 1 2]
print(cols)#[0 1 2]

# Select rows from original DataFrame based on assignment
result1 = df_sorted.iloc[rows * len(cost_matrix.columns) + cols]
print(result1)
"""
   group id_a id_b  score
1      1   A1   B1   0.98
0      1   A2   B2   0.99
3      1   A3   B3   0.96
"""

OR
# Create cost matrix (negative scores) using pivot_table
cost_matrix = (df_sorted.pivot_table(index='id_a',
                                     columns='id_b',
                                     values='score',
                                     fill_value= -np.inf) )

print(cost_matrix)
"""
id_b    B1    B2    B3
id_a                  
A1    0.98  0.50  0.41
A2    0.93  0.99  0.40
A3    0.97  0.20  0.96
"""
# Handle missing values
rows, cols = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix.fillna(np.inf) *(-1) )  
print(rows)#[0 1 2]
print(cols)#[0 1 2]

